# Who portrayed Adrian Marcato in Roman Polanski's "Rosemary's Baby"?

Tags: rosemarys-baby

He only appears in a few frames of the dream sequence, but his likeness is otherwise shown in various photographs and the oil painting above the fireplace in the Castevet's living room.

[image: screencap of Adrian Marcato]

Who portrayed Adrian Marcato in Roman Polanski's *Rosemary's Baby*?

Comment: Attention Close voters:  This is not an ID question.  Not sure why there are 2 close votes on this question for being ID <face palm>

Answer (score 8):

My best educated guess is [Max Wagner](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0906022/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t89) which is found in [full cast list](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063522/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_cl_sm) as *Man in Dream Sequence (uncredited)*, and the only actor with [similar face](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0906022/mediaviewer/rm811451392/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk)